# Is there a way to create a GUI in python, like in VisualStudio or AndroidStudio?

Tags: python, wxpython

I wanted to know if there is a program like VisualStudio or AndroidStudio for python.
I mean, a program that can create a visual GUI and I just need to program the buttons I had planed in the GUI I made.

Comment: Which platform are you looking to deploy?

Comment: As already outlined in the other answers, there are GUI editors for wxPython, but they are not just as well integrated as the GUI editor for VisualStudio or Qt Creator. The reason for this may be that layouting the GUI in wxWidgets/wxPython is tricky for a beginning, but very powerful, as soon as you have learned to use sizers properly (especially when altering the GUI during runtime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick web search brings up a few possibilities:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonPit%20Apps#Programming:_GUI_tools
- http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/GUI%20Programming%20in%20Python

Like @kartikg3 asked, what platform are you working/deploying on?

Comment: i work with noteped++ , in python 2.7.9.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific; by 'platform' I meant 'operating system'. Since you're using Notepad++, I guess you're using Windows, right?

Answer (score 3):

PySide or PyQT require QT which allows you to use Qt Creator.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator

It's a bit of a workaround but the libraries come with a script (e.g. pyside-uic for pyside) which can convert qt creator files into python classes. You'll also need to setup another class which reads and creates the gui's, but this is all documented for pyside online here:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtCreator_and_PySide

Comment: OP tagged their question with 'wxpython', so not sure QT applies!

Comment: I saw that one, but then wxPython wasn't mentioned in the question so assumed they're open to ideas.

Comment: Good point; your answer is also useful for other people who are looking for a Python GUI designer.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped a lot.
i tagged 'wxpython' just for search editor for this class.